# Replace a control character with another control character

Tags: text-processing, sed, special-characters

A csv file is being generated with a form feed (`\f`) character. This makes it hard to read in excel, etc.

How can I convert the form feed character into a newline (`\n`) character?

All my searches so far show how to replace control character with a literal character, not with another special character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/\f/\n/g' file
```

Other `sed`s:

```
sed "$(printf 's/\f/\\\n/g')" file
```

Or with `tr`:

```
tr '\f' '\n' <file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\f/\n/g' file
```

The `-i` is to overwrite the file in-place. For in-place editing with `tr`:

```
tr '\f' '\n' < file 1<> file
```